# Can't reach OpenVPN server over the internet

Tags: vpn, openvpn, raspberry-pi, pihole

I'm struggling since quite some time to get my OpenVPN Server running on my raspberry-pi which already has PiHole running on it. The TLS key negotiation times out after 60 seconds and I don't know why. I port forwarded it in my router on the port 1194 for ipv4 and ipv6.

Also if I change the Ip in the config (the .ovpn file) to the servers local ip in my home network it works. It just doesn't work if I try to connect over the internet. I have ipv6 and ipv4. If required I can attach logs but I would need the path to where they are.

Edit: I'm using my mobile to test the connection over its mobile data. My provider uses DS-lite does that cause any problems?

My ovpn file

```
dev tun 
proto udp 
remote my.ip 1194 
resolv-retry infinite 
nobind 
persist-key 
persist-tun 
remote-cert-tls server 
auth SHA512 
cipher AES-256-CBC 
ignore-unknown-option block-outside-dns 
block-outside-dns 
verb 3
```

My server config

```
local 192.168.178.32 
port 1194 
proto udp 
dev tun 
ca ca.crt 
cert server.crt 
key server.key 
dh dh.pem 
auth SHA512 
tls-crypt tc.key 
topology subnet 
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0 
server-ipv6 fddd:1194:1194:1194::/64 
#push "redirect-gateway def1 ipv6 bypass-dhcp" 
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt 
push "dhcp-option DNS 192.168.178.32" 
keepalive 10 120 
cipher AES-256-CBC 
user nobody 
group nogroup 
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
crl-verify crl.pem
```

`192.68.178.32` is my pihole which I use as a DNS and DHCP server.

My ifconfig output

```
root@raspberrypi:~# ifconfig 
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500 
        inet 192.168.178.32  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.178.255 
        inet6 fe80::8f18:fb44:a5f1:af38  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link> 
        inet6 2a02:8071:219f:9000:28f6:566f:32c8:105d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global> 
        inet6 2a02:8071:219f:9000::1a1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x0<global> 
        ether b8:27:eb:db:1c:f4  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 96919  bytes 9369972 (8.9 MiB) 
        RX errors 0  dropped 43039  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 61668  bytes 47669565 (45.4 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Lokale Schleife)
        RX packets 139811  bytes 9665320 (9.2 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 139811  bytes 9665320 (9.2 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

tun0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.8.0.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  destination 10.8.0.1
        inet6 fddd:1194:1194:1194::1  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::7ff1:9b78:4550:cf04  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 100  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 1  bytes 72 (72.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 83  bytes 15448 (15.0 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

My phone log with verb 4

```
08:05:52.021 -- ----- OpenVPN Start -----
08:05:52.021 -- EVENT: CORE_THREAD_ACTIVE
08:05:52.024 -- OpenVPN core 3.git:released:662eae9a:Release android arm64 64-bit PT_PROXY
08:05:52.024 -- Frame=512/2048/512 mssfix-ctrl=1250
08:05:52.025 -- UNUSED OPTIONS
4 [resolv-retry] [infinite]
5 [nobind]
6 [persist-key]
7 [persist-tun]
11 [ignore-unknown-option] [block-outside-dns]
12 [block-outside-dns]
13 [verb] [4]
08:05:52.025 -- EVENT: RESOLVE
08:05:52.028 -- Contacting my.ip via UDP
08:05:52.029 -- EVENT: WAIT
08:05:52.033 -- Connecting to [my.ip]:1194 (my.ip) via UDPv4
08:06:02.025 -- Server poll timeout, trying next remote entry...
08:06:02.027 -- EVENT: RECONNECTING
08:06:02.032 -- EVENT: RESOLVE
08:06:02.050 -- Contacting my.ip:1194 via UDP
08:06:02.051 -- EVENT: WAIT
08:06:02.064 -- Connecting to [my.ip]:1194 (my.ip) via UDPv4
08:06:12.028 -- Server poll timeout, trying next remote entry...
08:06:12.030 -- EVENT: RECONNECTING
08:07:16.869 -- ----- OpenVPN Stop -----
```

My Pc log in the same LAN with verb 4

```
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000  
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000 
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000  
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000 
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000  
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000  
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000 
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000    
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000 
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000  
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000                                                                                                                                                       
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED                                                                                                                                                       
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED                                                                                                                                                       
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED                                                                                                                                                       
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED                                                                                                                                                       
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED                                                                                                                                                       
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED                                                                                                                                                       
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED                                                                                                                                                       
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED                                                                                                                                                       
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED                                                                                                                                                       
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED                                                                                                                                                       
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED                                                                                                                                                       
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED                                                                                                                                                       
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   pkcs11_pin_cache_period = -1                                                                                                                                                         
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   pkcs11_id = '[UNDEF]'                                                                                                                                                                
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   pkcs11_id_management = DISABLED                                                                                                                                                      
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   server_network = 0.0.0.0                                                                                                                                                             
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   server_netmask = 0.0.0.0                                                                                                                                                             
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   server_network_ipv6 = ::                                                                                                                                                             
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   server_netbits_ipv6 = 0                                                                                                                                                              
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   server_bridge_ip = 0.0.0.0                                                                                                                                                           
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   server_bridge_netmask = 0.0.0.0                                                                                                                                                      
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   server_bridge_pool_start = 0.0.0.0                                                                                                                                                   
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   server_bridge_pool_end = 0.0.0.0                                                                                                                                                     
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   ifconfig_pool_defined = DISABLED                                                                                                                                                     
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   ifconfig_pool_start = 0.0.0.0                                                                                                                                                        
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   ifconfig_pool_end = 0.0.0.0                                                                                                                                                          
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   ifconfig_pool_netmask = 0.0.0.0                                                                                                                                                      
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   ifconfig_pool_persist_filename = '[UNDEF]'                                                                                                                                           
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   ifconfig_pool_persist_refresh_freq = 600                                                                                                                                             
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   ifconfig_ipv6_pool_defined = DISABLED                                                                                                                                                
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   ifconfig_ipv6_pool_base = ::                                                                                                                                                         
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   ifconfig_ipv6_pool_netbits = 0                                                                                                                                                       
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   n_bcast_buf = 256                                                                                                                                                                    
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   tcp_queue_limit = 64                                                                                                                                                                 
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   real_hash_size = 256                                                                                                                                                                 
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   virtual_hash_size = 256                                                                                                                                                              
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   client_connect_script = '[UNDEF]'                                                                                                                                                    
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   learn_address_script = '[UNDEF]'                                                                                                                                                     
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   client_disconnect_script = '[UNDEF]'                                                                                                                                                 
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   client_config_dir = '[UNDEF]'                                                                                                                                                        
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   ccd_exclusive = DISABLED                                                                                                                                                             
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   tmp_dir = 'C:\Users\maxim\AppData\Local\Temp\'                                                                                                                                       
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   push_ifconfig_defined = DISABLED                                                                                                                                                     
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   push_ifconfig_local = 0.0.0.0                                                                                                                                                        
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   push_ifconfig_remote_netmask = 0.0.0.0                                                                                                                                               
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   push_ifconfig_ipv6_defined = DISABLED                                                                                                                                                
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   push_ifconfig_ipv6_local = ::/0                                                                                                                                                      
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   push_ifconfig_ipv6_remote = ::                                                                                                                                                       
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   enable_c2c = DISABLED                                                                                                                                                                
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   duplicate_cn = DISABLED                                                                                                                                                              
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   cf_max = 0                                                                                                                                                                           
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   cf_per = 0                                                                                                                                                                           
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   max_clients = 1024                                                                                                                                                                   
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   max_routes_per_client = 256                                                                                                                                                          
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   auth_user_pass_verify_script = '[UNDEF]'                                                                                                                                             
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   auth_user_pass_verify_script_via_file = DISABLED                                                                                                                                     
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   auth_token_generate = DISABLED                                                                                                                                                       
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   auth_token_lifetime = 0                                                                                                                                                              
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   auth_token_secret_file = '[UNDEF]'                                                                                                                                                   
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   vlan_tagging = DISABLED                                                                                                                                                              
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   vlan_accept = all                                                                                                                                                                    
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   vlan_pvid = 1                                                                                                                                                                        
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   client = ENABLED                                                                                                                                                                     
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   pull = ENABLED                                                                                                                                                                       
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   auth_user_pass_file = '[UNDEF]'                                                                                                                                                      
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   show_net_up = DISABLED                                                                                                                                                               
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   route_method = 3                                                                                                                                                                     
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   block_outside_dns = ENABLED                                                                                                                                                          
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   ip_win32_defined = DISABLED                                                                                                                                                          
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   ip_win32_type = 3                                                                                                                                                                    
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   dhcp_masq_offset = 0                                                                                                                                                                 
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   dhcp_lease_time = 31536000                                                                                                                                                           
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   tap_sleep = 0                                                                                                                                                                        
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   dhcp_options = DISABLED                                                                                                                                                              
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   dhcp_renew = DISABLED                                                                                                                                                                
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   dhcp_pre_release = DISABLED                                                                                                                                                          
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   domain = '[UNDEF]'                                                                                                                                                                   
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   netbios_scope = '[UNDEF]'                                                                                                                                                            
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   netbios_node_type = 0                                                                                                                                                                
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021   disable_nbt = DISABLED                                                                                                                                                               
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021 OpenVPN 2.5.0 x86_64-w64-mingw32 [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [PKCS11] [AEAD] built on Oct 28 2020                                                                                      
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021 Windows version 10.0 (Windows 10 or greater) 64bit                                                                                                                                     
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021 library versions: OpenSSL 1.1.1h  22 Sep 2020, LZO 2.10                                                                                                                                
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021 MANAGEMENT: TCP Socket listening on [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:25341                                                                                                                           
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021 Need hold release from management interface, waiting...                                                                                                                                
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021 MANAGEMENT: Client connected from [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:25341                                                                                                                             
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'state on'                                                                                                                                                             
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'log all on'                                                                                                                                                           
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'echo all on'                                                                                                                                                          
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'bytecount 5'                                                                                                                                                          
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold off'                                                                                                                                                             
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold release'                                                                                                                                                         
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021 Outgoing Control Channel Encryption: Cipher 'AES-256-CTR' initialized with 256 bit key                                                                                                 
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021 Outgoing Control Channel Encryption: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication                                                                                       
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021 Incoming Control Channel Encryption: Cipher 'AES-256-CTR' initialized with 256 bit key                                                                                                 
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021 Incoming Control Channel Encryption: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication                                                                                       
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021 Control Channel MTU parms [ L:1621 D:1156 EF:94 EB:0 ET:0 EL:3 ]                                                                                                                       
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021 Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1621 D:1450 EF:121 EB:406 ET:0 EL:3 ]                                                                                                                       
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021 Local Options String (VER=V4): 'V4,dev-type tun,link-mtu 1601,tun-mtu 1500,proto UDPv4,cipher AES-256-CBC,auth SHA512,keysize 256,key-method 2,tls-client'                             
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021 Expected Remote Options String (VER=V4): 'V4,dev-type tun,link-mtu 1601,tun-mtu 1500,proto UDPv4,cipher AES-256-CBC,auth SHA512,keysize 256,key-method 2,tls-server'                   
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]my.ip:1194                                                                                                                  
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021 Socket Buffers: R=[65536->65536] S=[65536->65536]                                                                                                                                      
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021 UDP link local: (not bound)                                                                                                                                                            
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021 UDP link remote: [AF_INET]my.ip:1194                                                                                                                                                   
Tue Feb 23 08:14:48 2021 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1614064488,WAIT,,,,,,                                                                                                                                               
Tue Feb 23 08:15:48 2021 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)                                                                                     
Tue Feb 23 08:15:48 2021 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed                                                                                                                                                        
Tue Feb 23 08:15:48 2021 TCP/UDP: Closing socket                                                                                                                                                                
Tue Feb 23 08:15:48 2021 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, process restarting                                                                                                                                   
Tue Feb 23 08:15:48 2021 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1614064548,RECONNECTING,tls-error,,,,,                                                                                                                             
Tue Feb 23 08:15:48 2021 Restart pause, 5 second(s)
```

I hope somebody has an idea why it's not working. Thanks already in advance.

Comment: are you testing the external access from inside your LAN? if so you need a router that supports Hairpinning, a feature usually reserved for enterprise grade routers. have you tried testing it from a remote location?

Comment: I added to my question that I'm testing with my phone. I'm using a fritzbox 6591 cable and in a forum somebody answered it would indeed support Hairpinning.

Comment: I suspect that the broken link here is the port forward. In 2021, most residential ISPs do not let customers use their public IP to receive inbound traffic. Please create a dummy http server on your Pi, forward that, then go to `canyouseeme.org` and see if it can connect through port 80.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it. I had a dual stack lite (ds lite) connection and tried to use an online portmapping service which didn't work... Then I called my ISP and they gave me Dual Stack (an ipv4 address and an ipv6 address). Now it works perfectly fine.

When I asked this question I didn't know that I had ds lite aswell as what it is. Still thanks to everyone.